# empapi subscribe not working lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event

I have created a lwc component (which for community) inside which I'm subscribing to a platform event being published via trigger.

However, the subscribe is not working at all even after platform event is published successfully.

Below is the code snipper

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError, setDebugFlag, isEmpEnabled } from 'lightning/empApi'
export default class Cors_videoFeedback extends LightningElement {
    channelName = "/event/Feedback__e";
    subscription = {};
    
    connectedCallback() {
        this.handleSubscribe();
        this.registerErrorListener();
    }

    handleSubscribe() {
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, (response) => this.messageCallback(response)).then(response => {
            console.log('Subscription request sent to: '+JSON.stringify(response.channel));
            this.subscription = response;
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
    messageCallback(response){
        console.log('response '+JSON.stringify(response));
    }

    registerErrorListener() {
        // Invoke onError empApi method
        onError(error => {
            console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            // Error contains the server-side error
        });
    }
```

The **Subscription request sent to** console never prints and I don't even see any errors. Does this mean the component isn't subscribed to platform event?

Below is the piece of code called from after insert & after update:

```
public static void sendFeedbackNotifications(Map<id, My_Feedback__c> feedbacks, Map<id, My_Feedback__c> articleFeedbacksOld) {
            List<Feedback__e> feedbackNotifications = new List<Feedback__e>();
            for (My_Feedback__c feedbackRec : feedbacks.values()) {
                feedbackNotifications.add(new Feedback__e(User_Id__c = feedbackRec.CreatedById, Record_Id = feedbackRec.Id));
            }
            if (!feedbackNotifications.isEmpty()) {
system.debug('publish now..');
List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(feedbackNotifications);
// Inspect publishing result for each event
for (Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        System.debug('Successfully published event.');
    } else {
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('Error returned: ' +
                        err.getStatusCode() +
                        ' - ' +
                        err.getMessage());
        }
    }       
}
```

}
}

The EventBus.publish returns no error and has a status **OPERATION_ENQUEUED**. **Successfully published event** message is printed in debug logs.

The Platform event's publish behaviour is **Publish immediately.**

Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Can you also share how the event is being raised?

Comment: In addition to the above please include what the PE's publication behaviour is. An "after commit" does not get queued after publication, for example, if there is no DML in the transaction that publishes the event.

Comment: Please add the details with an [edit] to your question rather than in comments.

Comment: @NagendraSingh I've added the method code which is executed from after update / after insert.

Comment: @PhilW - PE's publication behaviour is to "Publish immediately"

Comment: @sfdcnoob how sure are you that `EventBus.publish(feedbackNotifications);` is getting called? Can you put a debug log and check the same, also check the return type of `EventBus.publish(feedbackNotifications);` to make sure the event does gets triggered.

Comment: Where are you displaying this LWC?  lightning page? screen flow? digital experience? lightning out?

Comment: @NagendraSingh I already added a debug statement just before EventBus.publish and it was getting printed.

Comment: @NickCook digital experience.

Comment: You need to log the return values from `EventBus.publish` - this method returns success status, it does not fail with an exception if publication fails. This publication can fail if you assign a string that is too long to a text field in the event, for example. Please, please, please add detail by [edit], not by comment. It makes it easier for later visitors to understand the full question and any answer without digging through a long list of comments.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for your response. It returns no error and the status is OPERATION_ENQUEUED. I have updated the question with this information.

Comment: The code snippets does not include any error checking. Please show how you verified no errors being reported. Also, is `My_Feedback` a custom object (so `My_Feedback__c`)? Use [edit] again please.

Comment: @PhilW Done! :)

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is that you call subscribe from `connectedCallback`, which may be before the EMP API imports are fully resolved? All the examples I can find have a button to manage the subscription. Have you tried delaying your subscription to the first time the `renderedCallback` is called?

Comment: @PhilW I tried calling it from renderedcallback but that doesn't work either. :|

Comment: You did have a capital C in the method name, yes? Are you sure the method is called to do the subscribing?

Comment: @sfdcnoob Can you check in your experience site settings if Lightning Locker is enabled under Security & Privacy ? Also disable Allowed Cookies.

Comment: @PhilW the handleSubscribe method is called when the component loads.. but subscribe functionality seems be still not working.

Comment: @AnshulAgrawal any reason why disabling cookies might help? We use cookies in many different ways on our experience cloud pages, and disabling them could cause issues with other features.

Comment: @sfdcnoob Did you ever get the `subscribe()` call to work?  I'm seeing the same thing (although I'm trying to subscribe to a CDC event)... I call `subscribe()` with `.then()` and `.catch()` blocks, both of which log to console, and neither is ever called.  It's like the subscribe promise just never resolves, nor errors.